# How to manually set the string to color in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to manually set the strings to color when using the matplotlib plot figures?

For example, I have the following dataset.

```
# Generate data...
import pandas as pd   
seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x':np.random.random(10),
        'y':np.random.random(10),
        'z':np.random.choice(['yes','no'], 10)
    })

df
          x         y    z
0  0.417022  0.419195   no
1  0.720324  0.685220   no
2  0.000114  0.204452   no
3  0.302333  0.878117   no
4  0.146756  0.027388   no
5  0.092339  0.670468   no
6  0.186260  0.417305  yes
7  0.345561  0.558690   no
8  0.396767  0.140387   no
9  0.538817  0.198101  yes
```

I want to plot 'yes' as 'red' and 'no' as 'blue' with following code, but how can I set the colors?

```
# Plot...
plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, c= df.z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line will do what You want:

```
plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=['red' if x == 'yes' else 'blue' for x in df.z])
```